# Comparing two rational approximation of the same minimum

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-approximation, equidistribution

Let $P(x)=x^3-6x$. It is easy to see that on $[1,2]$, $P$ reaches its minimum at $x=\sqrt{2}$. Among all the fractions with denominator dividing $n$, the two closest ones are $a_n=\frac{\lfloor n\sqrt{2} \rfloor}{n}$ and $b_n=\frac{\lceil n\sqrt{2} \rceil}{n}$.

**Question :** is it true that the natural density of the $n\geq 1$ such that
$P(a_n)\lt P(b_n)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ ? 
In other words, if $r_N$ denotes the number of $n$'s in $[1,N]$ such that $P(a_n) \lt P(b_n)$, does 
$$\frac{r_N}{N}\to \frac{1}{2} \ \textrm{when} \ N \to \infty\tag{1}$$ ?

**What I tried :** with PARI-GP, I realized that the following much stronger 
property holds for $N\leq 10^6$ :

$$ 0 \leq \frac{r_N}{N}-\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{8}{N}$$

and both the lower and upper bounds are attained very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true: the natural density of those $n$ with $P(a_n)<P(b_n)$ is $1/2$. To see this, writing for brevity $u_n:=\lfloor n\sqrt 2\rfloor$ and $v_n=\lceil n\sqrt 2\rceil$, notice that the inequality $P(a_n)<P(b_n)$ can be written as
  $$ \left(\frac{u_n}n\right)^3 - 6\,\frac{u_n}n < \left(\frac{v_n}n\right)^3 - 6\,\frac{v_n}n; $$
equivalently,
  $$ \frac{v_n-u_n}n\,\frac{u_n^2+u_nv_n+v_n^2}{n^2} > 6\,\frac{v_n-u_n} n, $$
or
  $$ v_n^2+v_nu_n+u_n^2 > 6n^2. $$
Observing that $v_n=u_n+1$, this is further equivalent to
\begin{align*}
  3u_n^2+3u_n+1 &> 6 n^2, \\
  u_n^2+u_n &\ge 2n^2, \\
  (u_n+0.5)^2 &> 2n^2, \\
  u_n + 0.5 &> n\sqrt 2, \\
  \{n\sqrt 2\} &< 0.5, \tag{$\ast$} 
\end{align*}
where $\{n\sqrt 2\}=n\sqrt 2-u_n=n\sqrt 2-\lfloor n\sqrt 2\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $n\sqrt 2$. Finally, the natural density of those $n$ satisfying ($\ast$) is $0.5$, as a very special particular case of the well-known [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem).